# Can't get 3d objects to stop from overlapping

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've recently finished my project on A* pathfinding, following Sebastian Lague's playlist on Youtube. However, and I believe that was the case for him as well, I can't get the seekers (which are capsules) from entering each other. It almost worked when I gave them rigidbodies, but then they started teleporting everywhere and were being generally very buggy.

Here's the Coroutine that makes the seekers follow the shortest path found:

```
IEnumerator FollowPath()
{
    bool followingPath = true;
    int pathIndex = 0;
    transform.LookAt(path.lookPoints[0]);

    float speedPercent = 1;

    while (followingPath)
    {
        Vector2 pos2D = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.z);
        while (path.turnBoundaries[pathIndex].HasCrossedLine(pos2D))
        {
            if (pathIndex == path.finishLineIndex)
            {
                followingPath = false;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                pathIndex++;
            }
        }

        if (followingPath)
        {
            if (pathIndex >= path.slowDownIndex && stoppingDst > 0)
            {
                speedPercent = Mathf.Clamp01(path.turnBoundaries[path.finishLineIndex].DistanceFromPoint(pos2D) / stoppingDst);
                if (speedPercent < 0.01f)
                {
                    followingPath = false;
                }
            }

            Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(path.lookPoints[pathIndex] - transform.position);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, Time.deltaTime * turnSpeed);
            transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * speed * speedPercent, Space.Self);
        }
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

What's making them go forward is the `transform.Translate()` method toward the end. I'd really appreciate it if someone could help me out with this. Let me know if I should've included more parts of my code.

Answer (score 1):

`transform.Translate()` just moves a gameobject, it doesn't know or care what else exists in the world.

If you're using rigidbodies, you want to use `myRigidBody.MovePosition()`.
If you aren't, then you need to find a way to manually detect and handle collisions.

More information here:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ixM2W2tPn6c
- https://forum.unity.com/threads/differences-between-transform-translate-rigidbody-velocity-and-rigidbody-moveposition.537899/
- https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html

Comment: Thanks! I actually already found a fix, but I really appreciate your help! However I will still implement your solution, as it will probably fix bugs I haven't yet encountered.

Comment: @TheWalrus collision detection/resolution is an unending nightmare. Welcome to game development!

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out I am a fool, and the capsule is actually the child of an empty GameObject which has the script (I did this in order to change the pivot point of the object).

All I had to do was remove the collider and the rigidbody from the capsule itself and add them to the parent object, and now everything works.